Angular SPA & C# API - How to secure APIs?
I am building a public-facing SPA using Angular frontend and c# .net backend.  JWT will be used to authenticate users.  Is there a way to prevent users obtaining the JWT token from current session and accessing the APIs directly?

No. Anything that the application running on user's device receives or does can be reconstructed with enough dedication. Web just makes this simpler. That being said, what is it that you're actually trying to achieve?

I agree with Zdeněk Jelínek, I guess you're worried that users will be able to access all the resources after they get the JWT token? If so, you should check this document Role-based authorization in ASP.NET Core. Even the common user get the token, he still can't get the api protected by Administrator Role.

I want to prevent a user from obtaining a JWT and using this to perform a data dump by accessing the API's directly.  I understand that we should only expose the data that users should see in API's anyway, but if they have access to a users table (for example), I want to prevent them from accessing the API directly and iterating to get access to all available users (for example).

For Secure API we can use
ASP.NET Core Identity provides APIs that handle authentication, authorization, and identity management
May be below link are useful
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-api-authorization?view=aspnetcore-8.0

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
